# Enthought Canopy connect to server

Tags: python, enthought, canopy

I have Canopy installed on a local OSX computer and on a headless Linux server elsewhere. I would like to run Canopy locally, but use a venv on the server, connected via ssh. The purpose of this is to use the local Canopy software for rendering/etc., but the server for computation and storing of files.

If possible, this would be preferable to X11 forwarding, which is slooow. I typically use NX, but Canopy and NX are not playing nicely together, which is [a known issue](https://support.enthought.com/entries/21873380-Running-Canopy-Linux-via-remote-display-VNC-remote-X-display-).

Is this possible?

Comment: You forgot to ask a question.